# meaning of the phrase 'fix the broken glass'

Tags: expressions

Can the phrase

> fix the broken glass

mean to fix the situation?

Comment: Hello, 186. Have you done any research on this?

Comment: I'm closevoting as Primarily Opinion-based. In principle I suppose the words *could* be used metaphorically as suggested by OP. But it's certainly not a standard idiom, and I think it would be unwise for non-native speakers to "experiment" with English in this way.

Comment: "Mend the fences" is an idiom that would have the same meaning as metaphorical "fix the broken glass".

Comment: @TRomano: In the "real world", I'm inclined to associate fixing broken glass/windows with renovating a dilapidated/abandoned *house*. But metaphorical *mending of **fences*** almost always refers to restoring amicable *relationships* (between people, countries, etc.) that have become undesirably antagonistic.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is in reference to the "broken windows" approach to policing that's supposedly been applied (in a figurative sense) in New York City.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really fix broken glass any more than you can unspill milk. I think the saying would refer to something that cannot be fixed or would have a fix that is a compromise (less perfect than before it was broken). This is different than mending a fence, which can be done quite successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It can mean that, if used **metaphorically**.

> "metaphor" (noun) A figure of speech in which a word or phrase that ordinarily designates one thing is used to designate another, thus making an implicit comparison, as in "a sea of troubles". [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metaphor)

Examples of metaphor:

- “He was drowning in paperwork.”
- "How could he marry a snake like that?"
- "The committee shot her ideas down one by one."
- "His head was spinning with new ideas."

Comment: So could 'mop up and replace the spilt milk'.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've heard this phrase before, meaning to "solve a problem that resulted from someone's behavior". I think people would understand if you used it to generally mean "fix an interpersonal problem" or "clean up damage and find a solution".

Edit: I would say that it has a different meaning than "mend the fences" - because the image I get of "fixing glass" is more about handling a specific situation than working together with someone to repair a relationship.